# SQL Sending attach query in email as .csv

Tags: sql

I am trying to send an query as an attached .CSV in a email. Here is what I have.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='bdorner@fascinations.net',
@profile_name= 'MyMailProfile',
@subject='new Items',
@body='New Items',

@query= 'select itemlookupcode, * from Item where 
(datecreated BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, - 100, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND DATEADD(day, - 0,   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
',
@attach_query_result_as_file=1
@query_attachment_filename = 'test.csv'
```

I keep getting a error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '@query_attachment_filename'.

I do have an email that send out a query in a body of an email. If that code will help let me know.

Thank you for the Help,
 Brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a comma :

```
@attach_query_result_as_file=1**,**
@query_attachment_filename = 'test.csv'
```

When you get a syntax error, always look for syntax problems in your query!

Comment: Now I get Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 504
Query execution failed: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server RMSGP, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Item'.

Comment: @Brian there seems to be some problems in your query. First you cannot do "itemlookupcode, * " (in most DBMS), it should be "itemlookupcode" only or "*".

Comment: Got that error, need to use the full db. but now get Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
File attachment or query results size exceeds allowable value of 1000000 bytes.

Comment: Check the Size Limit in database Mail. Mail queued now.

Comment: Any good links or do you know how to format the .csv? It is putting all the row information in on column..

Comment: @Brian it seems that the email you are trying to send is too big, maybe you could try splitting it in multiple emails (working with the dates "BETWEEN")

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma after the `@attach_query_result_as_file`.  That's why you get a syntax error pointing at the next line after.